# R persp3d "bty" paramter not working

Tags: r, plot, 3d, perspective, surface

My data is a lower triangular matrix of correlations. I want to plot a surface plot and overlay a mesh grid on it. For some reason the bty parameter is not doing anything. I want the plot to be encapsulated in a lined/grid box. Anyone know why I can't specify type of box here? [image: Surface plot of correlations for varying weights in two assets]

```
 nbcol = 100
 red = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Reds"))(nbcol)
 ccol  = cut(corr, nbcol)

 persp3d( z= corr,  
          x = seq(0, 100, length.out = nrow(corr)), 
          y = seq(0, 100, length.out = ncol(corr)), 
          color =red[ccol], 
          box = T, 
          aspect = c(100, 100, 70), 
          bty = "b2",  
          axes = T, 
          xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = ""    )

 surface3d(x=seq(0, 100, length.out = nrow(corr)), 
           y=seq(0, 100, length.out = nrow(corr)), 
           z= corr, 
           back = "lines" , front = "lines")

 axes3d(box = T, c('z+-','x-','y++'))
```

Comment: Could it be that the function you are looking for is "persp3D" from the library "plot3D" and that you are currently using "persp3d" from "rgl"? "persp3D" has the bty argument.

Comment: Yes thank you, I realised last night that the examples I was seeing were using the persp3D function. Unfortunately persp3D doesn't allow me to overlay the mesh surface and add extra axes. Looks like I want functionality from both functions!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out persp3d doesn't have bty as a parameter and examples that had caused me to think I could use it were actually based on persp3D.